# multi variable calculus problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]
In this problem putiing it in limit  1 / n f(k/n) form it turns out to be π\4  which is not in the option . its answer is given as the first three options . how can it have three possible answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't always interchange integration and limit operations. Easiest way is to integrate before taking the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^\infty \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}dx&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^\infty\frac{d(nx)}{1+(nx)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{M\to \infty}\arctan(nx)\Big|_a^M\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan(na)\right).
\end{align*}
We notice that if $a=0$, then $L=\frac\pi2$, $a>0$, then $L=0$ and $a<0$, then $L=1$. This comes from following properties:
$$\arctan 0=0,$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\arctan x=\frac\pi2,$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\arctan x=-\frac\pi2.$$

Comment: OK ,but it also has π and 0 as its possible answers . how is it possible?